# Has Realview Imaging created a 3D holography device?

Tags: technology

In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIj2xEd_z78), [RealView Imaging](http://www.realviewimaging.com/) is claiming to be able to create 3D holography in mid-air, without glasses.

I didn't fully understand [their page about their technology](http://www.realviewimaging.com/?page_id=158). They claim they are using [Spatial Light Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator).

Have they invented a new technology? Is it something we already know, wrapped in clever marketing? Is this real?

Comment: I think the key is the large black screen in the back where the laser light will come from, the image will then be only visible with that screen as the background

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I agree with you. That's what I get from the videos [here](http://www.realviewimaging.com/?page_id=185) at least.

Comment: Beware of false dichotomies. It could be a careful (and novel) application of an existing technology - neither a new technology nor merely a marketing exercise.

Comment: Their first usage example doesn't look anything like marketing videos: http://www.newscenter.philips.com/pwc_nc/main/standard/resources/healthcare/2013/3D-holographic-imaging/Philips-Live-Interventional-Imaging-Modalities.jpg

Comment: On their own page: http://www.realviewimaging.com/?page_id=225 It's clear that the actual experience and setup isn't anything like what the promotional video implies.

Answer (score 2):

A patent filed by them clearly mentions that the system generates a non-holographic 3-D images.http://www.google.com/patents/US8500284

If it is a holographic display then they must have had speckles in the reconstruction. Which tells that it is a kind of volumetric projection. But anyways it is a good and useful piece of technology in this decade. And our wait for a holographic display continues....